# tikz - positioning pics just like a node

Tags: tikz-pgf

Say below code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
        % colmat
pics/colmat/.style={code={
        \tikzset{colmat/.cd,#1}  \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/colmat/##1}}%
        \edef\m{\pv{m}}%
        \edef\w{2}%
        \foreach \row [count=\j] in \m  {
            \foreach \r/\g/\b [count=\i] in \row {
                \fill[fill={rgb,255:red,\r; green,\g; blue,\b}] (\i*\w,\j*\w) rectangle ++(\w,\w);
            }%foreach
        }%foreach
}},colmat/.cd,m/.initial={{255/0/0}},/tikz/.cd,
    %
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{
        box/.style={draw,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm}
    }
    \def\clst{
        {200/10/10},
        {10/10/200},
        {10/200/200}%
    }
    \node[box] (A) at (0,0) {A};
    \foreach \pos in {left,right,above,below} {
        \node[\pos=1 of A,matrix] (B-\pos) {\pic{colmat={m=\clst}};\\};
    }

    \node[left=6 of A,box] (C) at (0,0) {C};
    \foreach \pos in {left,right,above,below} {
        \node[\pos=1 of C,box] (D) {D};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I wish the pic block around A just behavior the same as node D around C. I found some similar questions but still not figure out the right way to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this question came up before. The trick is to wrap the `pic` in a `matrix` node (to be clear, this is a 1x1 matrix). This works unless you want to put the `pic` in a matrix, but there you can use the `pic` itself, or want to use a matrix in the `pic`, at least as of now.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
pics/mypic/.style={code={
        \tikzset{mypic/.cd,#1}  \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mypic/##1}}%
        \edef\m{\pv{m}}%
        \foreach \row [count=\j] in \m  {
            \foreach \r/\g/\b [count=\i] in \row {
                \fill[fill={rgb,255:red,\r; green,\g; blue,\b}] (\i-1,\j-1) rectangle ++(1,1);
            }%foreach
        }%foreach
    }},mypic/.cd,m/.initial={{255/0/0}},/tikz/.cd,
%
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{
        box/.style={draw,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm}
    }
    \def\clst{
{31/18/12}%
    }
  \node[box] (A) at (0,0) {A};
  \foreach \pos in {left,right,above,below} {
    \node[\pos=1 of A,matrix] (B-\pos) {\pic{mypic={m=\clst}};\\};
  }

\node[left=6 of A,box] (C) at (0,0) {C};
\foreach \pos in {left,right,above,below} {
    \node[\pos=1 of C,box] (D) {D};
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One simple way of dealing with larger pics is to count the entries and making them symmetric.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
        % colmat
pics/colmat/.style={code={
        \tikzset{colmat/.cd,#1}  
        \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/colmat/##1}}%
        \edef\m{\pv{m}}%
        \foreach \row [count=\j] in \m  {\xdef\mydimj{\j}
            \foreach \r/\g/\b [count=\i] in \row {\xdef\mydimi{\i}}}
        \typeout{\m,\mydimi,\mydimj}
        \edef\w{2}%
        \foreach \row [count=\j] in \m  {
            \foreach \r/\g/\b [count=\i] in \row {
                \fill[fill={rgb,255:red,\r; green,\g; blue,\b}]
                 (\i*\w-\mydimi/2,\j*\w-\mydimj/2) rectangle ++(\w,\w);
            }%foreach
        }%foreach
}},colmat/.cd,m/.initial={{255/0/0}},/tikz/.cd,
    %
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{
        box/.style={draw,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm}
    }
    \def\clst{
        {200/10/10},
        {10/10/200},
        {10/200/200}%
    }
    \node[box] (A) at (0,0) {A};
    \foreach \pos in {left,right,above,below} {
        \node[\pos=1 of A,matrix] (B-\pos) {\pic{colmat={m=\clst}};\\};
    }

    \node[left=6 of A,box] (C) at (0,0) {C};
    \foreach \pos in {left,right,above,below} {
        \node[\pos=1 of C,box] (D) {D};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, never know such usage. is it a matrix inside a node? usually matrix include many nodes as cells.

Comment: @lucky1928 This is just a trick. I am sometimes wondering if one should export the tricks from `\def\tikz@do@matrix{...}` in `tikz.code.tex` to define a wrapper for pics and potentially other objects. (BTW, `tikz.code.tex` is a nice source of all sort of tricks such as `execute at begin matrix` and several more which never made it to the manual but work.) None of this requires the `matrix` library.

Comment: Sounds like if color block width 1 works fine, but if changed width to 2, the distance above is different. I have updated my question. not sure what's wrong!

Comment: @lucky1928 I added a simple fix for that. Will try to add a more general fix a bit later.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

Just change `right=1 of A` to `right=0 of A`, i.e.:

```
\pic[right=0 of A] (B) {mypic={m=\clst}};
```

Another possibility is in `tikzpicture` options (or in `tikzset`) define

```
node distance=0cm
```

and then write

```
\pic[right=of A] (B) {mypic={m=\clst}};
```

Comment: Thanks, I expect it match center horizontally!

Comment: @lucky1928, from your question this doesn't follow. Also now is not clear, what is your problem. Please edit your question and elaborate it.

Comment: sorry for the confuse, updated with more better sample.

Comment: @lucky1928, (i) ˙pic` is not a node, (ii) its positioning depends from defined anchors in `pic`, It seems, that in it is your case defined at bottom left corner of `pic`, (iii) sorry, I'm lost in your code for `pic`, so I'm not able to correct it. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

#### Updated:

With the drawing code

```
\foreach \row [count=\j] in \m {
  \foreach \r/\g/\b [count=\i] in \row {
    \fill[fill={rgb,255:red,\r; green,\g; blue,\b}]
      (\i * \w, \j * \w) rectangle ++(\w,\w);
  }
}
```

- every filled square has its south west corner at `(\i*\w, \j*\w)` and north east corner at `(\i*\w + \w, \j*\w + \w)`.
- For `\i` ranging from `1` to `\mydimi` and `j` ranging from `1` to `\mydimj` (inclusive), the constructed bigger rectangle has its south west corner at `(1*\w, 1*\w)` and north east corner at `(\mydimi*\w + \w, \mydimj*\w + \w)`.
- Hence the center of that bigger rectangle is at `(.5*\mydimi*\w + \w, 0.*\mydimj*\w + \w)`. To put that center at the origin `(0, 0)`, we shift the coordinate by using

```
shift={(-0.5*\mydimi*\w - \w, -0.5*\mydimj*\w - \w)}
```

A full example, note that I have slightly simplified the `pic` definition.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  % colmat
  pics/colmat/.style={code={
    \tikzset{colmat/#1}
    \foreach \row [count=\j] in \pic@colmat@m {
      \xdef\mydimj{\j}
      \foreach \r/\g/\b [count=\i] in \row {\xdef\mydimi{\i}}
    }
    \edef\w{2}%
    \foreach \row [count=\j] in \pic@colmat@m {
      \foreach \r/\g/\b [count=\i] in \row {
        \fill[fill={rgb,255:red,\r; green,\g; blue,\b},
         shift={(-0.5*\mydimi*\w - \w, -0.5*\mydimj*\w - \w)}]
          (\i * \w, \j * \w) rectangle ++(\w,\w);
      }%foreach
    }%foreach
  }},
  colmat/m/.estore in=\pic@colmat@m,
  colmat/m/.initial={{255/0/0}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
    box/.style={draw,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm}
  }
  \def\clst{
    {200/10/10},
    {10/10/200},
    {10/200/200}%
  }
  \node[box] (A) at (0,0) {A};
  \foreach \pos in {left,right,above,below} {
    \pic[\pos=2 of A] (B-\pos) {colmat={m=\clst}};
  }

  \node[left=6 of A,box] (C) at (0,0) {C};
  \foreach \pos in {left,right,above,below} {
    \node[\pos=1 of C,box] (D-\pos) {D};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Old answer:

Unlike node, a pic has a fixed anchor. That anchor is the `(0, 0)` inside its drawing commands. See pgf manual, sec. 18.2, paragraph *The location of a pic*.

In your pic definition, `(0, 0)` is at the south west corner of filled square. Hence tikz puts every south west corner of pic `mypic` to positions like `left=1 of A`.

Inside the definition of pic, moving `(0, 0)` to the center of filled square solves your problem. Here I use a `shift` option to offset. It is better to adjust the coordinates used in drawing commands of `mypic`, to keep its center at origin.

```
% before
\fill[fill={...},                   ] (\i-1,\j-1) rectangle ++(1,1);
% after
\fill[fill={...}, shift={(-.5, -.5)}] (\i-1,\j-1) rectangle ++(1,1);
% for updated example in question, a shift of (0, -3) is required.
```

Comment: right, but the input array will change, so the center point is not a fixed value.

Comment: @lucky1928 How will that array change?

Comment: updated my question, that array can be any 2-d color combination MxN.

Comment: @lucky1928 Updated my answer. The update is mainly about how to calculate the required shift coordinate.

Comment: It's great, would you please explain `\tikzset{colmat/#1}` in the pic definition?

Comment: @lucky1928 It functions similar to `\tikzset{colmat/.cd,#1}` in your example. If `#1` is just `m=...`, then `\tikzset{colmat/.cd,#1}` and `\tikzset{colmat/#1}` are the same. If `#1` contains two or more key-value pairs, then `.cd` is required.